# Locating Picture hotspots - Determining nearby picture hotspots (Intellectual Ventures) - Patent Application - PRIOR ART REQUEST

Tags: prior-art-request, pre-grant, intellectual-ventures, us20140012609a1

**AN OVERBROAD PATENT ON finding the nearby picture hotspots based on location data and user data** - This application from [Intellectual Ventures](http://www.intellectualventures.com/) seeks to patent the idea of...Transmit location data and user data over a wireless network via the communication module, and receive notification data from a network connected server over the wireless network in response to the transmitted location data.! 10 minutes of your time can help narrow US patent applications before they become patents.  [Follow @askpatents](https://twitter.com/AskPatents) on twitter to help.

**QUESTION** - Have you seen anything that was **published before 10/28/2010** that discusses:

> - Determining nearby picture hotspots based on location data and user data

If so, please submit evidence of prior art as an answer to this question. We welcome multiple answers from the same individual.

**EXTRA CREDIT** - User data may include data retrieved from the digital storage.

**TITLE: Locating picture hotspots based on location data and user data**

**Summary**:  [Translated from Legalese into English] Transmit **location data** and **user data** over a **wireless network** via the **communication module**, the **location data** is provided by the **GPS receiver module** based in part on stored **user data**, receive **notification data** from a network connected server over the **wireless network** in response to the transmitted **location data**, the **notification data** indicates that the device is within a vicinity of a **hot spot location**, and the notification includes **directional information** associated with finding the **hot spot location**.

- **Publication Number**: [US 20140032715 A1](https://www.google.com/patents/US20140032715)
- **Application Number**: US 14/043,934
- **Assignee**: Intellectual Ventures
- **Prior Art Date**: Seeking prior Art **predating** 10/28/2010
- **Open for Challenge at USPTO:** Open through 7/29/2014
- **Link to Google Prior Art Search** - ["Find Prior Art"](https://www.google.com/patents/related/US20140032715#c=0&d1=10%2F28%2F2010)

**Claim 1** requires each and every step below:

> A device comprising:
>
> 1. a communication module;
> 2. a GPS receiver module; and
> 3. a processor configured to:
>
> 3a. transmit location data and user data over a wireless network via the communication module, wherein the location data is provided by the GPS receiver module based in part on stored user data; and
>
> 3b. receive notification data from a network connected server over the wireless network in response to the transmitted location data, wherein the notification data indicates that the device is within a vicinity of a hot spot location, wherein the notification includes directional information associated with finding the hot spot location.

In English this means:

> A device comprising:
>
> 1. A communication module;
> 2. A GPS receiver module; and
> 3. A processor configured to:
>
> 3a. Transmit location data and user data over a wireless network via the communication module,
>
> 3b. The location data is provided by the GPS receiver module based in part on stored user data; and
>
> 3c. Receive notification data from a network connected server over the wireless network in response to the transmitted location data,
>
> 3d. The notification data indicates that the device is within a vicinity of a hot spot location, and
>
> 3e. The notification includes directional information associated with finding the hot spot location.

Good prior art would be evidence of a system that did each and every one of these steps prior to 10/28/2010

You're probably aware of ten pieces of art that meet this criteria already... separately, the applicant is claiming The notification data includes directional information from a current location to the hotspot location and the current location is based on the location data

---

**"Nearby Picture Hotspots" from the Applicant**

[image]

---

*What is good prior art? Please see our [FAQ](https://patents.stackexchange.com/faq#prior-art).*

*Want to help? Please vote or comment on submissions below. We welcome you to [post your own request for prior art](https://patents.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/prior-art-request+pre-grant) on other questionable US Patent Applications.*

---

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example of potential prior art for this patent application: [US20100002122 A1](https://www.google.com/patents/US20100002122?dq=US20100002122&ei=85c9U6u4L5TLsASI_oCoAw)

According to the description, this patent application describes a system and method that provide techniques for sharing digital photos, in which a user of a portable electronic device may seek out a location at which another electronic device was used to capture a photo.

If you are aware of other potential prior art references, please post it here.

Answer (score 1):

[This TED talk from 2007](http://www.ted.com/talks/blaise_aguera_y_arcas_demos_photosynth) shows a system that detects if images are related spatially, not by GPS, but by analyzing the image. It also provides directionality information. [GPS information is also generated](http://photosynth.net/discussion.aspx?cat=6b63cb81-8b57-4d5d-a978-41d5509bf59a&dis=6dcaca05-1232-41da-9089-471d7485689f).

Answer (score 0):

Here is your prior art. The locations of HotSpots (Clickable hypermedia link) on your Picture HotSpot is the individual images of the collarge

Comment: http://web.archive.org/web/19970401002943im_/http://www.algonet.se/~jason/